# How to solve phpmyadmin errors?

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently I installed xampp software and where i start apache and mysql server but when i go to localhost/phpmyadmin then i've got some errors and i can't be able to fix those errors.

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Comment: can you post the sanitized config of phpmyadmin, you have there an error

Comment: Pretty self explanatory. Your credentials are invalid or the host is defined wrong. Without more details how can we help?